# Android to servlet image upload to be saved on server

Tags: java, android, servlets, file-upload

I have created a servlet that accepts an image from my android app.I am receiving bytes on my servlet, however, I want to be able to save this image with the original name on the server. How do I do that. I dont want to use apache commons. Is there any other solution that would work for me?

thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Send it as a [multipart/form-data](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2388.html) request with help of `MultipartEntity` class of Android's builtin [HttpClient API](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/client/HttpClient.html).

```
HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://example.com/uploadservlet");
MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity();
entity.addPart("fieldname", new InputStreamBody(fileContent, fileContentType, fileName));
httpPost.setEntity(entity);
HttpResponse servletResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
```

And then in servlet's `doPost()` method, use [Apache Commons FileUpload](http://commons.apache.org/fileupload) to extract the part.

```
try {
    List<FileItem> items = new ServletFileUpload(new DiskFileItemFactory()).parseRequest(request);
    for (FileItem item : items) {
        if (item.getFieldName().equals("fieldname")) {
            String fileName = FilenameUtils.getName(item.getName());
            String fileContentType = item.getContentType();
            InputStream fileContent = item.getInputStream();
            // ... (do your job here)
        }
    }
} catch (FileUploadException e) {
    throw new ServletException("Cannot parse multipart request.", e);
}
```

---

> *I dont want to use apache commons*

Unless you're using Servlet 3.0 which supports `multipart/form-data` request out the box with [`HttpServletRequest#getParts()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getParts()), you would need to reinvent a multipart/form-data parser yourself based on [RFC2388](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2388.html). It's only going to bite you on long term. Hard. I really don't see any reasons why you wouldn't use it. Is it plain ignorance? It's at least not that hard. Just drop `commons-fileupload.jar` and `commons-io.jar` in `/WEB-INF/lib` folder and use the above example. That's it. You can find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2422468/how-to-upload-files-in-jsp-servlet/2424824#2424824) another example.